# Como utilizar o summarise?

Tags: r, dplyr

Tenho um `DF` com dados de energia e gostaria de agrupar os dados por atividade (pois estão divididos por estado e eu quero fazer o agregado para Brasil) e somar estes dados para cada data. Estava tentando utilizar o `group_by` com o `summarise`, porém, não está retornando da forma que eu gostaria.

Código:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

CCEE <- read_excel("Dados/Consumo de energia.xlsx", sheet = "CCEE")

colnames(CCEE) <- c("data", "classe", "atividade", "submercado", "UF", "unidade", "value")

CCEE <- CCEE %>%
  mutate(atividade = str_to_title(atividade),
         data = as_date(data)) %>%
  filter(classe == "Consumidor Livre") %>%
  select(-c(unidade, submercado, classe)) %>%
  group_by(data, atividade) %>%
  summarise(value = round(sum(value), 2)) %>%
  arrange(atividade, data)
```

Com o código desta forma, ele retorna o seguinte erro:

```
# Error in order(atividade, data) : objeto 'atividade' não encontrado
```

Se eu remover o `arrange`, retorna o somatório de todos os valores, dessa forma:

```
#    value
#1 8832167
```

Eu gostaria que os dados ficassem dessa forma, com a soma por atividade para cada uma das datas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os dados são baixados em `csv` e eu tive que transformá-los em `excel`, mas já testei com os dados em formato `csv` e retornou o mesmo erro.

Meu dput:

```
dput <- structure(list(Data = structure(c(1533081600, 1533081600, 1533081600, 
                                          1533081600, 1533081600, 1533081600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
                       Classe = c("Autoprodutor", "Autoprodutor", "Autoprodutor", "Autoprodutor", "Autoprodutor", "Autoprodutor"), 
                       `Ramo de atividade` = c("ALIMENTÍCIOS",  "ALIMENTÍCIOS", "ALIMENTÍCIOS", "ALIMENTÍCIOS", "ALIMENTÍCIOS", "COMÉRCIO"), 
                       Submercado = c("NORDESTE", "SUDESTE / CENTRO-OESTE", "SUDESTE / CENTRO-OESTE", "SUL", "SUL", "SUDESTE / CENTRO-OESTE"), 
                       Estado = c("Pernambuco ", "Minas Gerais", "Mato Grosso", "Santa Catarina", "Rio Grande do Sul", "São Paulo"), 
                       `"Consumo (MWm)"` = c("Consumo (MWm)", "Consumo (MWm)", "Consumo (MWm)", "Consumo (MWm)", "Consumo (MWm)", "Consumo (MWm)"), 
                       `Consumo (MWm)` = c(0.24033975, 0, 0.908708333, 3.044405, 1.443036542, 0.16408)), 
                  .Names = c("Data", "Classe", "Ramo de atividade", "Submercado", "Estado", "\"Consumo (MWm)\"", "Consumo (MWm)"), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Sem rodar o código não dá para ter certeza, mas você sobreescreve a variável, será que você não rodou depois de ter alterado ela uma primeira vez? Tá com cara de ser isso. Recomendo rodar todas as linhas juntas. Acho que vai dar certo

Comment: Não entendi muito bem como rodar todas as linhas juntas, pode me explicar melhor? Obrigado!

Comment: Roda o `pipe`, logo depois de ler os dados. A impressão que dá é que você rodou o pipe duas vezes seguidas

Comment: Ah! Já fiz isso várias vezes. o ```pipe``` nem chega a rodar por conta do erro do ```arrange```. Como eu disse, se eu retirar o ```arrange```, ai ele soma todos os valores e não é o que eu gostaria.

Comment: Pode tirar o arrange... mas roda o pipe só uma vez depois de ler

Comment: Na verdade a forma de garantir se o problema é esse ou não é mudando o nome da variável criada pelo pipe para, por exemplo, `CCEE2`

Comment: Fechei o R e abri novamente, renomeei a variável de saída para ```teste``` e ocorreu o mesmo problema de somar todos os valores e retonar um ```DF``` com uma linha.

Comment: Editar a pergunta com a saída de `dput(head(CCEE, 30))` é melhor que um link. Há muitos usuários que não gostam de descarregar dados e no meu caso nem sequer está a funcionar e não vou tentar descobrir porquê.

Comment: Aqui toda normal. Vou botar o caso num reprex como resposta. Depois removo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teste isto:

```
# glimpse(CCEE)
CCEE <- CCEE %>%
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.character, as.factor) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(atividade = stringr::str_to_title(atividade),
                data = lubridate::as_date(data),
                value = as.numeric(value)) %>%
  # dplyr::filter(classe == "Consumidor Livre") %>% 
  # No df disponibilizado nao ha o fator "Consumidor Livre" para `classe`
  dplyr::select(-c(unidade, submercado, classe)) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(data, atividade) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(data, atividade) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(value = round(sum(value), 2)) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

Perceba que você tinha algumas colunas que deveriam ser fatores (`as.factor`). A função `glimpse` pode te ajudar para situações como esta, elucidando a classe de suas variáveis.

Também modifiquei um pouco a ordem dos acontecimentos, passando o `arrange` para uma etapa anterior ao `group_by`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aqui retornou um ```DF``` com o somatório de todos os valores da mesma forma que coloquei na pergunta.

Comment: Veja na imagem que há o agrupamento por data. Manda seu `df` com mais data e classes distintas, que talvez seja possível ajustar.

Comment: Obrigado pelas soluções, reinstalei o ```R``` e o ```dplyr``` e funcionou! Acredito que deve ter sido algum arquivo corrompido dentro do pacote.